# Is there a way to select a row in an 2D numpy array with conditions for each column in the row?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing

I'm trying to select one row from a 2D numpy array. This selection is based on conditions of the value in the columns of the row.

As an example this is my 2D array:

```
| V1  | V2  | V3 | V4  | Q1 | Q2  |
|-----|-----|----|-----|----|-----|
| 0.1 | 0.5 | 3  | 7   | 5  | 10  |
| 0.3 | 0.8 | 4  | 5   | 15 | 20  |
| 2   | 15  | 6  | 0.5 | 1  | 0.5 |
```

This table could have around 5000 or more rows, and if I have the values of all of the V1,V2,V3,V4 I want to look up in this array and find Q1 and Q2.

So if I have:

```
V1 = 0.3
V2 = 0.8
V3 = 4
v4 = 5
```

I would like it to return the full row, or just the Q values:

```
Q1 = 15
Q2 = 20
```

Is there any way of selecting this data on the rows? 
I found a solution online with:

```
np.where((table[:,0] == V1) & (table[:,1] == V2) & (table[:,2] == V3) & (table[:,3] == V4))
```

But with this many entries the time it takes is quite a while, is there anyway to do it faster?

Comment: you mentioned your condition `V1 = 0.3 V2 = 0.8 V3 = 4 v4 = 5` like this. Will it be same when you select multiple rows or you want to select different rows on basis of different conditions ?

Comment: Yes, the conditions will change, the search will always be different

Answer (score 0):

Why not convert it into a Pandas dataframe?  Then we have the following:

```
import pandas as pd

ddict = {
    'V1':[0.1,0.3,2],
    'V2':[0.5,0.8,15],
    'V3':[3,4,6],
    'V4':[7,5,0.5,],
    'Q1':[5,15,1],
    'Q2':[10,20,0.5],
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(ddict)

### DataFrame.loc(<row>, <column>) will return values for the columns if the row conditions are met.
df.loc[(df['V1'] == 0.3) & (df['V2'] == 0.8) & (df['V3'] == 4) & (df['V4'] == 5), ['Q1','Q2']]
```

Output:

```
   Q1    Q2
1  15  20.0
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with:

```
import numpy as np

table = np.array([[ 0.1 , 0.5 , 3  , 7   , 5  , 10  ],
[ 0.3 , 0.8 , 4  , 5   , 15 , 20  ],
[ 2   , 15  , 6  , 0.5 , 1  , 0.5 ]])

np.where(np.all(np.equal(a[:,:4], [0.3, 0.8, 4, 5]),axis=1))
```

This will give you the row number to look up. you can assign it to a variable like `row` and then just grab the Q1/Q2 data with `a[row,-2:]`.

I recommend commenting out the parens in each layer in order to figure out how this works, but in brief you are looking at columns `:4` (i.e. 0-3) in the array in order to find which ones match the description.  You break down just the columns you need and then check if any of them equal the result you seek, and then "all" them up across the rows (`axis=1`), and then show `where` the rows have all elements equaling true.